# How to draw google line chart from JSON data

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-visualization, linechart

I need help with drawing chart that is auto updating. I currently have two php files, one which gets data from MySQL database and turns it into JSON get_json.php, and the other that turns gotten data into chart, linechart.php.
Chart appears, but there is nothing on it, and both axis go from 0 to 1, and I need x axis to be TimesStamp column from database.
Here are codes:

get_json.php

```
<?php


$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'u644759843_miki', 'plantaze2020!') or die('Error connecting to server');

mysqli_select_db('u644759843_plantazeDB', $con); 

// write your SQL query here (you may use parameters from $_GET or $_POST if you need them)
$query = mysqli_query('SELECT `FlowRate`, `ProductPurity`, `TimesStamp` FROM `Precizno ProductPurity` ORDER BY TimesStamp DESC LIMIT 10');

$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    /* define your DataTable columns here
     * each column gets its own array
     * syntax of the arrays is:
     * label => column label
     * type => data type of column (string, number, date, datetime, boolean)
     */
    // I assumed your first column is a "string" type
    // and your second column is a "number" type
    // but you can change them if they are not
    array('label' => 'FlowRate', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'ProductPurity', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'TimesStamp', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $temp = array();
    // each column needs to have data inserted via the $temp array

    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['ProductPurity']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['FlowRate']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['TimesStamp']); // typecast all numbers to the appropriate type (int or float) as needed - otherwise they are input as strings

    // insert the temp array into $rows
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

// populate the table with rows of data
$table['rows'] = $rows;

// encode the table as JSON
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

// set up header; first two prevent IE from caching queries
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

// return the JSON data
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

linechart.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <script>
      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

//AJAX Call is compulsory !

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "/nitrogengenerator/get_json.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

          // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

          var options = {
               title: 'Nitrogen Generator',
              is3D: 'true',
              width: 800,
              height: 600
            };
          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          // Do not forget to check your div ID
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
        </script>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    // First load the chart once 
                    drawChart();
                    // Set interval to call the drawChart again
                    setInterval(drawChart, 5000);
                    });
    </script>

    <!-- Kraj koda za grafik -->
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="chart_div"> </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you want x-axis to be date, it will need to be the first column in the data table. you can pass a json date to google charts, using their [date string format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#dates-and-times-using-the-date-string-representation).

Comment: Alright, but why is my chart still empty, do you see any problems in code?

Comment: have you checked the browser's console for errors? (press F12 on most)

Comment: I tried it, but no errors appeared. The chart is created, but nothing is drawn into it, and values go from 0 to 1 on both axis.

Comment: will you please share a sample of the data? --> `console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));`